# How does Static function mapped internally?

Tags: c, static

In what way the static function is different from normal function in the compiler view? we all know that static function is local to the file, but how the compiler make this more secure as file specific?does it do any kind of restriction's in .o file during compilation?

Comment: It can add a little note in the object file saying "this function is public" or "this function is private."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `.o` file there are a lot of things. You can see them by running `objdump -x file.o`.

But the pieces that interest us are:

- The code. Here the code of all the functions from the `.c` file is written.
- The exports table. Here, there are the names of the exported functions (and variables, too), together with the position in code.

A static function simply does not add an entry in the exports table.